# Loopback4 - Call REST API with OpenAPI definition

Tags: loopback4

I'm new to Loopback4 and trying to call REST endpoint using lb4 datasource and have some questions:

1. Does `lb4 datasource` and `lb4 service` bound to datasource generates proxy methods to call REST endpoints based on OpenAPI definition?
2. If #1 is yes, what is the correct way to do it?

I tried what is in [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/OpenAPI-connector.html) guide:

1. Create a LoopBack 4 DataSource with OpenAPI connector using the lb4 datasource command.
2. Create a service that maps to the operations using the lb4 service command.

But it doesn't generate any method in service nor datasource.

PS: I'm using [Swagger Petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) definition to do this sample. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

*Hi from the LoopBack team*

In the first case where you use `lb4 datasource` and `lb4 service` to generate the proxy, you need to add the operation mappings in the datasource and the functions in the service manually. See https://github.com/dhmlau/loopback4-external-apis/blob/master/src/datasources/restds.datasource.json for an example.

But as you mentioned, if you have the OpenAPI/swagger spec, you can simply use the `lb4 openapi --client` command.

Comment: Hi Diana, you're right! And this answer will be useful to who doesn't have OpenAPI spec. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the right tool to do it:

1. Just call `lb4 openapi --client`
2. Select existing datasource (or create a new one [setting up datasource](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Calling-other-APIs-and-web-services.html))
3. Select controller

Stubs will be generated.

To call the service, just inject it in Controller and execute generated methods.